# Qt LineEdit search in the site

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

В моем приложении у меня есть LineEdit и мне нужно при вводе, к примеру - "Собака" на определенном сайте выводился результат поиска. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать? Через Менеджера или, как второй вариант, используя JSON?

```
connect_to_the_selected_site;
find_SearchField_using_XML_or_JSON;
connect_My_LineEdit_and_SearchField;
GET_request;
*Reply;
parse_result();
```

Все равно пока тишина. Даже не знаю за что схватиться, нужно чтобы кто-то в голову вдолбил направление, по которому мне начинать двигаться. Перелопатил кучу всего, но понимания не пришло. Попробовал через обработчик событий на `Error'ы`, Но в ответ на `readAll` получаю пустоту. Через документацию вычитал, что необходимо использовать `finished()`, но я не понимаю что это такое. В ответ получаю в консоли `QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::finished()`

```
QNetworkAccessManager *rat = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("https://coop-land.ru"));
    QNetworkReply *reply = rat->get(req);
    connect(rat, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finished()));
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
```

Comment: делаете гет-запрос через QNetworkAccessManager (если сайт с https, то надо собрать qt с поддержкой https). В ответ на гет-запрос вы получите html документ, с которым уже можно работать или как с текстом или через QDomDocument

Comment: ```QNetworkAccessManager rat;
    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("https://coop-land.ru/"));
    QNetworkReply *reply = rat.get(req);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

    qDebug() << "Error debug: " << reply->error() << "\n"
             << "ReadAll: " << reply->readAll() << "\n";``` В ответ я получаю - Error debug:  QNetworkReply::NoError 
 ReadAll:  ""